# Optimization of a voxel projection function

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, image-processing

I implemented a function to check if a voxel (3D pixel) is well projected on the space of a image (black and white silhouette) through a perspective camera. The function does the work but It need more optimization when I increase the number of voxel (when we pick the step as .05 or .08, etc).

```
(*convert vector from projective to euclidean form*)
    proj2Eucl[p_] := Module[{}, (
       Delete[p, -1]/p[[-1]]
       )]

(*vox={x,y,z,1} voxel in projective form, p=3*4 matrix projection of a camera, sh=silhouette (black and white)*)


    projectVoxelSil[vox_, p_, sh_] := Module[{pts, h, w, X, Y}, (
       (*this projection gives the index of the pixel*)
       pts = proj2Eucl[p.vox];
       (*silhouette dimension*)
       {w, h} = ImageDimensions[sh];
(*convert from indices to coordinates to use correctly PixelValue[]*)
       X = Round[pts[[1]]];
       Y = h - Round[pts[[2]]];
(*Test if this voxel fall on the silhouette (white pixel)*)
       If[PixelValue[sh, {X, Y}] == 1., Delete[vox, -1], 
        Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
       )]
```

**Test:**
[image: image Test]

```
p = {{-0.0000, 179.9370, -340.0000, 1020.0000},
  {179.2531, 0.0000, -256.0000, 768.0000},
  {0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000, 3.0000}}
step=.1
 vox= Flatten[ParallelTable[
    projectVoxelSil[{x + step/2, y + step/2, z + step/2, 1}, p, silb0], {x, -1, 
     1, step}, {y, -2, 2, step}, {z, 0, 3, step}], 2];




    drawProjectedVoxel[vox_, silh_, p_] := Module[{ptsproj, ptseucl, f}, (

       ptsproj = p.# & /@ (Append[#, 1] & /@ vox);
       ptseucl = proj2Eucl[#] & /@ ptsproj;
(*convert from indices to coordinates*)
       ptseuclc = ({#[[1]], 512 - #[[2]]}) & /@ ptseucl;
       Show[silh, Graphics[{Red, Point[#] & /@ ptseuclc}]]

       )]

drawProjectedVoxel[voxel, silb0, p]
```

[image: Resultat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is slow is that you call `PixelValue` for each voxel. (You also call `ImageDimensions[sh]` for each voxel when you only need to compute it once, but that's not a big deal.) Instead, you can use `ImageData` once on your silhouette, giving you all pixel values at once. Here is my suggestion:

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[silb0];
im = ImageData[silb0];
allvox = Reap[
   Do[
    With[{vox = {x + step/2, y + step/2, z + step/2, 1}},
     {X, Y} = Round[proj2Eucl[p.vox]];
     If[
      0 <= X <= w && 0 <= Y <= h && im[[Y, X]] == 1
      , Sow[Delete[vox, 4]]
      ]
     ], {x, -1, 1, step}, {y, -2, 2, step}, {z, 0, 3, step}]
   ][[2,1]];
```

This takes 0.4 seconds on my machine, contrary to 18 seconds with the `PixelValue` version.

Notice also that `ImageData` just gives a matrix of values corresponding to the pixel values of the image, so the `Dimensions` of `im` is `{h,w}` in this case. That's why we do `im[[Y,X]]` and not `im[[X,Y]]`. I also needed to add constraints on `X,Y` as they are sometimes projected outside the silhouette, which would have given a `Part::partw` error otherwise.

Comment: Can we combine With and Module to declare local variables like this:                projectVoxelSil[silh_, step_, p_] := Module[{X, Y, w, h, im, allvox}, (
   {w, h} = ImageDimensions[silh];
   im = ImageData[silh];
   allvox = 
    Reap[Do[With[{vox = {x + step/2, y + step/2, z + step/2, 1}}, {X, 
          Y} = Round[proj2Eucl[p.vox]];
        If[0 <= X <= w && 0 <= Y <= h && im[[Y, X]] == 1, 
         Sow[Delete[vox, 4]]]], {x, -1, 1, step}, {y, -2, 2, 
        step}, {z, 0, 3, step}]][[2, 1]])]

Comment: Did you try? ;) Looks fine to me, except you don't need to store the result in `allvox` if you only want to return it. But again, if you are gonna run this with many sets of voxels for the same silhouette, don't compute `ImageData[silh]` every time.

Comment: No. for each silhouette I apply this function  just 1 time.